# How to print KMeans intiatial parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

I am using PyCharm to run Kmeans using Iris data.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans()
print(kmeans)
```

When I run this, simply prints `KMeans()` But I would like it to print the following:

```
KMeans(n_clusters=8, *, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=300, tol=0.0001, precompute_distances='deprecated', verbose=0, random_state=None, copy_x=True, n_jobs='deprecated', algorithm='auto')
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run `kmeans.get_params()`. This will print out the parameters (default or custom) used while instantiating the function in a dictionary format.

Please refer this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! this exactly what I was looking for.